# Installing previous version of tar package

Tags: software-installation, tar, source-packages

My current version of tar is

```
p@p-ubuntu:~/ba/tar-1.25$ sudo apt-cache showpkg tar
Package: tar
Versions: 
1.27.1-1ubuntu0.1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 48033bf96442788d1f697785773ad9bb
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: 48033bf96442788d1f697785773ad9bb

1.27.1-1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 48033bf96442788d1f697785773ad9bb
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: 48033bf96442788d1f697785773ad9bb


Reverse Depends: 
  dpkg,tar 1.23
  tar:i386,tar
  dpkg,tar 1.23
  tar:i386,tar
  vfu,tar 1.20-1
  pristine-tar,tar 1.27-3
  patool,tar 1.26
  dump,tar 1.13.92-3
  amanda-common,tar 1.12
  dpkg,tar 1.23
  backuppc,tar 1.13
Dependencies: 
1.27.1-1ubuntu0.1 - libacl1 (2 2.2.51-8) libc6 (2 2.17) libselinux1 (2 1.32) bzip2 (0 (null)) ncompress (0 (null)) xz-utils (0 (null)) tar-scripts (0 (null)) cpio (1 2.4.2-38) cpio:i386 (1 2.4.2-38) dpkg-dev (3 1.14.26) dpkg-dev:i386 (3 1.14.26) cpio (3 2.4.2-39) cpio:i386 (3 2.4.2-39) tar:i386 (0 (null)) 
1.27.1-1 - libacl1 (2 2.2.51-8) libc6 (2 2.17) libselinux1 (2 1.32) bzip2 (0 (null)) ncompress (0 (null)) xz-utils (0 (null)) tar-scripts (0 (null)) cpio (1 2.4.2-38) cpio:i386 (1 2.4.2-38) dpkg-dev (3 1.14.26) dpkg-dev:i386 (3 1.14.26) cpio (3 2.4.2-39) cpio:i386 (3 2.4.2-39) tar:i386 (0 (null)) 
Provides: 
1.27.1-1ubuntu0.1 - tar:i386 
1.27.1-1 - tar:i386 
Reverse Provides: 
tar:i386 1.27.1-1ubuntu0.1
tar:i386 1.27.1-1
```

Now, I need to install 1.25 version of tar. Not sure how to find the exact version number.I tried this but its not working.

```
p@p-ubuntu:~/ba/tar-1.25$ sudo apt-get install  tar=1.26-4ubuntu1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.26-4ubuntu1' for 'tar' was not found
```

Comment: Why would you want that older version? Btw, obsolete package versions normally get removed from the official repositories when there is a newer one available (except when the updated version gets published in a different repository than the original one, like `main` and `updates` or `security`, then the both versions will coexist)

Comment: Im trying to build a yocto image and that needs  a older version of tar...Here is the related tkt to this issue- https://community.nxp.com/message/925882?commentID=925882#comment-925882  As per the ticket, they have recommended older version of tar package.

Comment: @user1050619 The ticket you linked says to download and install a **patch** for 1.27, not install an old version. As a matter of fact it's a reply for one of the comments describing a situation like yours.

Comment: @MichaelBay One item talks about the patch and other one asks to update the tar package. Thought updating to older package would vibe easier.

Comment: There's no such thing as "updating to an older package", that's *downgrading*.

Comment: That's correct, is there a way to downgrade to earlier version.

Comment: You may try to find, download and install the exact version you want if not in the repositories. *If* you succeed expect further problems down the road with that old code, other errors and possibly other missing dependencies.